# How do I access response headers while using RxJava2 and Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2, github-api, rx-java2, clean-architecture

### The Premise

I'm working on a simple app where I want to list out a user's GitHub repos in a RecyclerView. I'm using [this](https://api.github.com/users/libhide/repos) as my endpoint while building this.

### The Problem

The problem I'm facing is that the GitHub API returns only 30 repos in one go. To get more, I can append a `per_page=100` (100 is the maximum) to my query string; **But**, what do we do about users with more than 100 repos?

The solution the API [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/#basics-of-pagination) provide is to get the `next;` url from the "Link" response header to make a second API call.

How does one go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Response` class will let you access the headers. The GitHub client would have a method like:

```
@GET("/search/code")
Observable<Response<T>> getUser(...)
```

Inside `onNext()`, you'd do something like:

```
@Override
public void onNext(Response<T> response) {
    String next = response.headers().get("next");
}
```

Comment: Observable<Response<T>> tells me that `Type 'okhttp3.Response' does not have type parameters.` So, I tried the call with Observable<Response> and that lead to a `'okhttp3.Response' is not a valid response body type. Did you mean ResponseBody?` error. Thoughts?

Comment: You need the [Response class in Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Response.java). Not okhttp.